# Superpowered : Is there a way to save the output buffer to a file after applying the effects on audio?

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, superpowered

I am new to android and Superpowered. I was able to get the Superpowered CrossExample to work in Android. However I am unable to save the final output to a file. After processing the two players, is it possible to save the output buffer to a file? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SuperpoweredRecorder class. An example is available in the Examples_Windows folder. Check mainpage.xaml.cpp, understand and use the few lines of code there.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Comment: I added the recorder->start(destinationPath) and recorder->stop() based on toggle button click. I see that there is a file created but when I try to play it, there is no sound.

Comment: I found the solution. recorder->start(path) had to be called before initializing the audioIO.